# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)

Tags: wine, winetricks

I've had this problem numerous times when trying to install software in WINE, now I've come to the point where I have to install something in WINE. Installing the program works fine, as soon as I go to run it however I get the message
 Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime.
Runtime Error
I have installed the above package using wine tricks, but still nothing. Have goggled to try and find if I am missing Dependencies or anything obvious, but after that I am stuck. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [the known bugs Section at WineHQ for this software?](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20406) Have you tried installing it the recommended way? Does it work now? If not, move your wine configuration folders (.wine) somewhere safe, start with a new configuration, install the recommended way and try again. Hope this helps, good luck.